# Should a Windows 10 tag be removed, if a problem is related to Windows 10?

Tags: discussion

I found it important to add the `Windows-10` tag to this this question [Is there a way to force Windows to use Precision Touchpad drivers rather than Synaptics?](https://superuser.com/q/921215/549571) because it is mainly an issue of Windows 10.

Since Windows 10 is also more common than Windows 8, I thought this tag would be important if people use search engines to learn about this problem.
Is it not?

Comment: I've added the tag back again. In your suggested edit or flag you should have said that the answers are mostly for windows 10.

Comment: Or alternatively if the problem is across Windows versions use the more generic [tag:Windows] tag rather than having a whole raft of tags. We can only have 5 tags on a question, so less is more in this case.

Comment: @Mokubai But that's quite unspecific. Its not helping Windows XP, Windows Vista or Windows 7, because precision touchpads weren't invented at that time. And since only 3 tags had been used, we don't need to save on them. We can thing about removing tags if the limit of 5 is reached.

Comment: Just because most of the answers were about Windows 10 doesn’t mean the question author was using Windows 10.  In fact, most of those answers, are not even applicable to the question for that reason.  I am specifically talking about the answers that show Windows 10 settings instead of Windows 8.  The author specifically used the Windows 8 tag, which means they were using Windows 8, or I suppose it could mean they did not know any better and used a random tag.

Comment: @Ramhound You are completely right. And I can confirm that it also applies to Windows 10 and could add valuable information with the Windows 10 tag. What's bad about it?

Comment: @FrankBreitling so why not [tag:windows-8.1] as well, as it is almost certainly relevant there too? Why would we want 3 different tags telling us the exact same thing - that this is a problem with windows *in general* - when a single tag will do? It probably also affects the Server product line as well so [tag:windows-server-2012] and [tag:windows-server-2012-r2] so 5 tags. It is probably also relevant to [tag:windows-insider] builds as well. Sometimes just saying "this is relevant to **one single thing** I found" isn't enough and it is obvious this affects a broad swathe of the product line.

Comment: From the windows-10 tag: `For questions specific to Windows 10. Use [windows] instead for questions involving Windows in general.` this is obviously not a problem *specific to Windows 10*. Nor is it specific to Windows 8 any more. The question obviously has an impact across versions and is a general windows driver problem. Windows XP, Vista and 7 can largely be discounted as they are all EoL and their relevance to the current product line should be waning. What is relevant *now* is that this isn't a problem with one version. Does it happen on Windows 10? Yes. Is it specific to it? No.

Answer (score 5):

> I found it important to add the Windows-10 tag to this this question Is there a way to force Windows to use Precision Touchpad drivers rather than Synaptics? because it is mainly an issue of Windows 10.

Except the question was asked before Windows 10 was released.  So Windows 10 has nothing to do with that particular author's question.

> Since Windows 10 is also more common than Windows 8, I thought this tag would be important if people use search engines to learn about this problem. Is it not?

**It does not matter if Windows 10 is more popular than Windows 8.**  What matters what the author was using at the time the question was asked.  Answers should be focused on answering the author's question.  A question that was asked May 2015, more than likely, was using Windows 8.1 Update 1 instead of a Windows 10 Insider Preview (1507) build.

If a high quality answer applies to both Windows 8 and Windows 10 then it makes sense to update an existing question's tags to reflect that fact.  If that is not the case, then changing the question's tags, should not be done without significant thought on the impact with regards to the existing answers the question has received.

I don't actually see anything that would justify adding the Windows 10 tag to that question.  **The accepted answer is still accurate and applies to every supported version of Windows.**  The author never specifically specified they were using Windows 10.  The only mention of Windows 10 was in temporary commentary by other users.

> I thought the main impact of StackExchange comes from helping many users and not just one. Then the clearer its made where the solution applies, the more people can find it and profit from it.

That is something that is only true in specific situations. If a question was asked 60 days before Windows 10 was released, and the author of the question made no mention they were using Windows 10, then it doesn’t make sense to change the tag that was used to Windows 10.

Besides, just changing the tag of a question, is rarely helpful by itself.  In this case the question was asked over 5 years ago. Changing the tag won’t make the question easier to find.

I actually don’t agree with that first edit that added the Windows 10 tag in the first place. I absolutely, think removing the Windows 8 tag, was an unhelpful edit.

**The addition of the Windows tag was a compromise, I am willing to accept the judgment of a moderator on that decision, it probably was the correct tag in the first place.**

Comment: I thought the main impact of StackExchange comes from helping many users and not just one. Then the clearer its made where the solution applies, the more people can find it and profit from it.

Comment: @FrankBreitling - Updated my answer

Comment: @ I read it and agree that the new tags are less useful. Its also not what I suggested. I only suggested to add a Windows 10 tag. Unfortunately I don't understand your other new statements. Could you give an explanations for why they should be true?

Comment: @FrankBreitling - At the end of the day, an answer must answer a specific question, and in the example you have provide the question was about Windows 8.1 not Windows 10.   You won't be able to change my mind.  *The question should have always included the generic Windows tag*